# Trello API: Retrieve list name from a card

Tags: list, api, trello

I'm using Trello's API and I'm trying to retrieve the List name of the list of a defined card.

If I do

```
https://api.trello.com/1/cards/{idCard}?key={mykey}&token={mytoken}
```

This returns me all the informations about the card that I defined with the Id, and gives me the idList.

[image]
How can I obtain the list name of the card's list with only one query?

There is something similar to wordpress that let the user to retrieve all the information embedded in the json using the `_embed` tag in the query?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [the official document of /cards/{id}/{field}](https://developers.trello.com/v1.0/reference#cardsidfield). You can get any field like this, and in case of `idList`:

```
https://api.trello.com/1/cards/{idCard}/idList?key={mykey}&token={mytoken}
```

Another way:

```
https://api.trello.com/1/cards/{idCard}/list?key={mykey}&token={mytoken}&fields=id
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked doing https://api.trello.com/1/cards/{idCard}/list?key={mykey}&token={mytoken}&fields=name -> in this way a can retrieve the id and the name of the list!